# Am I doing this trigger delete incorrectly?

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables and if I delete a row from one table it should delete the other row from another table with the same 'item_id' but when I delete one it doesn't seem to delete the other, is my trigger incorrect?

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER del_CD
AFTER DELETE on Music_CD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Item 
    WHERE Item.item_id = Music_CD.item_id;
END $
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
WHERE Item.item_id = Music_CD.item_id;
```

with

```
WHERE Item.item_id = OLD.item_id;
```

And BTW you are missing a space in the last line

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks! Where is the comma suppose to go? All you put was 'DELIMITER ;' So i'm a little confused.

Also when I put 'NEW' it gives me an error saying "There is no NEW row in on DELETE trigger"

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer. It is `OLD` and not a comma but a space.